# Why does Ember.js / EAK autogenerate ApplicationController instead of using my explicit ApplicationController?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6, ember-app-kit

I'm using Ember App Kit (EAK).

The Ember Inspector / Chrome Dev Tools console shows this line when I load my index page:

```
*generated -> controller:application Object {fullName: "controller:application"}*
```

But I've explicitly created an Application Controller, which this Ember app apparently doesn't know about (since it's autogenerating an ApplicationController).

I'm trying to call a title property on my explicit Application Controller, and display it in my application template.

What am I doing wrong? The `{{title}}` in the template yields nothing.

(I suspect it has to do with the way EAK uses ECMAScript 6 modules via the ES6 Module Transpiler.)

---

/site/app/templates/application.hbs

```
{{title}}

{{outlet}}
```

---

/site/app/controllers/application.js

```
var ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    title: 'hello world'
});

export default ApplicationController;
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems ok to me. Which Ember.js and app-kit versions do you use?

I tried to replicate your issue but everything worked well. Can you please replicate my scenario and verify that it also works for you?

What I did:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:stefanpenner/ember-app-kit.git
$ cd ember-app-kit
$ npm install
```

Made these code changes (my git diff):

```
diff --git a/app/controllers/application.js b/app/controllers/application.js
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..9d34ee0
--- /dev/null
+++ b/app/controllers/application.js
@@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
+var ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
+    title: 'hello world'
+});
+
+export default ApplicationController;
diff --git a/app/templates/application.hbs b/app/templates/application.hbs
index d08c11f..a373a71 100644
--- a/app/templates/application.hbs
+++ b/app/templates/application.hbs
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 <h2 id='title'>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
+{{title}}

 {{outlet}}
```

and finally ran

```
$ grunt server
```

and when I opened localhost:8000 everything worked fine ("hello world" was rendered). Can you please try it out?

Comment: Your instructions worked perfectly for me, Petr.  Thank you very much.  I'm using the latest EAK with Ember.js 1.2.  I guess I need to go back and take another look at my code and EAK layout, and try to figure out what's different.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes helps to restart your grunt server.

Comment: Yes, I figured that one out the hard way. Thank you for the advice, though.